# Filtering date does not return correct data

Tags: oracle10g

I have the following query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT temp.*, ROWNUM AS rn
          FROM (  SELECT (id) M_ID,
          CREATION_DATE,
                         RECIPIENT_STATUS,
                         PARENT_OR_CHILD,
                         CHILD_COUNT,
                         IS_PICKABLE,
                         IS_GOLDEN,
                         trxn_id,
                         id AS id,
                         MASTER_ID,
                         request_wf_state,
                         TITLE,
                         FIRST_NAME,
                         MIDDLE,
                         LAST_NAME,
                         FULL_NAME_LNF,
                         FULL_NAME_FNF,
                         NAME_OF_ORGANIZATION,
                         ADDRESS,
                         CITY,
                         STATE,
                         COUNTRY,
                         HCP_TYPE,
                         HCP_SUBTYPE,
                         is_edit_locked,
                         record_type rec_type,
                         DATA_SOURCE_NAME,
                         DEA_DATA,
                         NPI_DATA,
                         STATE_DATA,
                         RPPS,
                         SIREN_NUMBER,
                         FINESS,
                         ROW_NUMBER ()
                            OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY full_name_fnf)
                            AS rp
                    FROM V_RECIPIENT_TRANS_SCRN_OP
                   WHERE 1 = 1
  AND creation_date  >= 
                       to_date( '01-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')   AND creation_date  <= 
                       to_date( '09-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                ORDER BY  CREATION_DATE DESC) temp
         WHERE rp = 1)
 WHERE rn > 0 AND rn < 10;
```

Issue is, that the above query does return data which has creation_date as '09-Sep-2015'.

NLS_DATE_FORMAT of my database is 'DD-MON-RR'.

Datatype of the column creation_date is date and the date format in which date is stored is MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Does `creation_date` have a time component that is not 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds?

Comment: Yes it does. The format of the date stored in the column creation_date is "9/9/2015 1:07:45 AM"

Comment: So clearly "9/9/2015 1:07:45 AM" is not less than or equal to "9/9/2015 0:00:00 AM", which is returned by `to_date( '09-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

Comment: So what do you suggest :)

Comment: @mustaccio thank you for notifying. I have used trunc(creation_date) instead of creation_date and I have got my desired result. Thank you again for notifying.

Comment: A better alternative would be `AND creation_date  < to_date( '10-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, as applying a function (`trunc()`) to the table column might prevent the use of index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your column `creation_date` has values with non-zero time components, and the result of `to_date( '09-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` has a *zero* time component, the predicate `creation_date  <= to_date( '09-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` is unlikely to match. As an example, "9/9/2015 1:07:45 AM" is clearly greater than "9/9/2015 0:00:00 AM", which is returned by your `to_date()` call.

You will need to take into account the time component of the Oracle `DATE` data type.

One option is to use the `trunc()` function, as you did, to remove the time component from values of `creation_date`. However, this may prevent the use of index on `creation_date` if it exists.

A better alternative, in my view, would be to reformulate your predicate as `creation_date < to_date( '10-Sep-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, which would match any time values on the date of 09-Sep-2015.